# CMStepCounter blocking UI activity in IOS7 for loop with async gcd

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

I am running a loop to break down the day and work out my active walking time.

The code works fine, and delivers the desired results. However, at the point of executing queryStepCountStartingFrom it blocks the UI for the period that the for loop is calling it.

I have tried removing the queryStepCountStartingFrom call from the code and replacing with a 10 second sleep, and have proved there is no issue with the UI when run in this way. I have also tried removing the activity within the loop that follows the queryStepCountStartingFrom and the issue exists. So I am now confident that the issue is with this one part of the code.

I am using GCD to run the code and would expect that the for loop should not interfere with the UI which is on the main thread. (When I say the UI, I have other screens, both modal and tabs, and I if I press these, he screen does not change until the for loop completes, although if the queryStepCountStartingFrom line is not there, and I instead add a sleep, the issue is not there). The delay also stops other areas of my code on the same screen from running a simple step count enumeration to get the current step count for the day.

Can someone advise why this issue occurs, and how I may correct it?

Many thanks.

```
- (void) getActiveTime {
    if([CMStepCounter isStepCountingAvailable])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
        CMStepCounter *stepCounter = [[CMStepCounter alloc] init];
        NSOperationQueue *checktimequeue = [NSOperationQueue new];
        checktimequeue.name = @"Check Time Queue";
        NSLog(@"START");
        __block NSInteger activeTime = 0;
        __block NSDate *activetimerangeNow = [NSDate date];

        for (NSDate *activetimerangeStart = [self startDateOfToday];
             [activetimerangeStart compare:activetimerangeNow] == NSOrderedAscending;
             activetimerangeStart = [activetimerangeStart dateByAddingTimeInterval:10])
        {
            NSDate *checkRangeStart = activetimerangeStart;
            NSDate *checkRangeEnd = [activetimerangeStart dateByAddingTimeInterval:10];
            [stepCounter queryStepCountStartingFrom:checkRangeStart
                                                 to:checkRangeEnd
                                            toQueue:checktimequeue
                                        withHandler:^(NSInteger numberOfSteps, NSError *error) {
                                            if (numberOfSteps > 1) {
                                                activeTime=activeTime+10;
                                            }
                                            NSComparisonResult result;
                                            result = [checkRangeEnd compare:activetimerangeNow];
                                            if(result==NSOrderedAscending){
                                                // still in loop
                                            }
                                            else if(result==NSOrderedDescending){
                                                // end of loop - date greater
                                                NSLog(@"rangeEnd = %@; dateCompare = %@",checkRangeEnd, activetimerangeNow);
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                [self callbackActiveTime:activeTime];
                                                });
                                            }
                                            else {
                                                // end of loop - dates are same
                                                NSLog(@"rangeEnd = %@; dateCompare = %@",checkRangeEnd, activetimerangeNow);
                                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                [self callbackActiveTime:activeTime];
                                                });
                                            }
                                        }];
             }
            };
            });
    }
}

- (void)callbackActiveTime:(NSInteger)activeTime {
    NSLog(@"Active Time = %d", activeTime);
    self.activeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f mins", (double)activeTime/60];
}
```

**EDIT**
I have just moved

```
NSOperationQueue *checktimequeue = [NSOperationQueue new];
            checktimequeue.name = @"Check Time Queue";
```

And have also swapped the GCD to BACKGROUND.

both above the loop, as I realised this would create many instances, however, the same issue remains.?

Any thoughts welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have resolved this by using a semaphore to wait for the response to the handler from the async process.

Create the semaphore as soon as I start each iteration inside the loop:-

```
sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
```

at the end of the loop (after the handler) wait:-

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Inside the handler, after the response has been received, signal completion:-

```
dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
```